# Where to find 'items' aggregation in class sap.m.List?

Tags: sapui5

I'm following the [walkthrough tutorial](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/bf71375454654b44af01379a3c3a6273) on Step:20 Aggregation Binding and in the code below, I cannot figure out where is it documented in the class [sap.m.List](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.List%23aggregations) that the *items* aggregation should be bound to the root path Invoices of the JSON data like `items="{invoice>/Invoices}"` in the code below.

**webapp/view/InvoiceList.view.xml (New)**

```
<mvc:View
   xmlns="sap.m"
   xmlns:mvc="sap.ui.core.mvc">
   <List
      headerText="{i18n>invoiceListTitle}"
      class="sapUiResponsiveMargin"
      width="auto"
      items="{invoice>/Invoices}" >
      <items>
         <ObjectListItem
            title="{invoice>Quantity} x {invoice>ProductName}"/>
      </items>
   </List>
</mvc:View>
```

It does state that the class [sap.m.List](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.List%23aggregations) has an aggregation (0..n) called *items* which can take items of the type [sap.m.ListItemBase](https://ui5.sap.com/#/api/sap.m.ListItemBase).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to the [Aggregation Binding](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f057786f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) topic in [Data Binding Module](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/68b9644a253741e8a4b9e4279a35c247) of Documentation.
Even the [Property binding](https://ui5.sap.com/#/topic/91f0652b6f4d1014b6dd926db0e91070) topic, will help you to understand the concept in a better way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply @PKV. I have read about binding and know how to use it. My question is more about how to find this usage in the API documentation. If I was not doing the walkthrough examples, I would have never known simply by reading the documentation that I need to assign, items="{invoice>/Invoices}"

Comment: API documentation will just provide what are the supported aggregations, properties, etc... for a control. In most of the cases they do not provide how to use it. Wish they had included a sample of how to use it. But as of today we have to rely on either Documentation or Samples page to learn how to use it. 
As you might already be aware, name of the aggregation will differ for each control. so if you are using a sap.m.Panel, you will be using something like content="{invoice>/Invoices}"